# Uploading file to API via cURL PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

I've been trying to upload a file to a remote API via CURL for the past few days with little luck, The code works perfectly on windows, and I get the desired returned output back from the API.

My issue is that once I move to a linux environment and I upload the file via CURL I get the error message below.

What I tried:
I thought perhaps permissions and the likes were the cause of my problem as it was saying that it cannot find the file, so I decided to modify my code slightly to upload to the server, move it into an upload folder then pick that file to send via curlfile but still no luck. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
"errors": [
    {
      "developerMessage": "Error while manipulating file /home/USER/public_html/top/tmp/client17.jpg due to a File system / Amazon S3 issue /usr/share/tomcat7/.fineract/top/documents/clients/1/8q9sr/home/USER/public_html/top/tmp/client17.jpg (No such file or directory)",
      "defaultUserMessage": "Error while manipulating file /home/USER/public_html/top/tmp/client17.jpg due to a File system / Amazon S3 issue /usr/share/tomcat7/.fineract/top/documents/clients/1/8q9sr/home/USER/public_html/top/tmp/client17.jpg (No such file or directory)",
      "userMessageGlobalisationCode": "error.msg.document.save",
      "parameterName": "id",
      "value": null,
      "args": [
        {
          "value": "/home/USER/public_html/top/tmp/client17.jpg"
        },
        {
          "value": "/usr/share/tomcat7/.fineract/top/documents/clients/1/8q9sr/home/USER/public_html/top/tmp/client17.jpg (No such file or directory)"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Here the code that I am using:

```
// UPLOAD NEW FILES
if(ISSET($_FILES))
{

    $uploads = array('guarantor_id_card', 'guarantor_payslip_1', 'guarantor_payslip_2', 'guarantor_payslip_3', 'guarantor_bank_1', 'guarantor_bank_2','guarantor_bank_3' );
    $postFields = array();

    // for creating documents

    foreach($uploads as $k => $v)
    {

        // GET  UPLOAD NAME FROM ARRAY 
        $upload_name = $v;

        if(empty($_FILES[$upload_name]['error']))
        {

            $uploaddir = getcwd() . "/tmp/";
            $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES[$upload_name]['name']);

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$upload_name]['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
              echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
            } else {
               echo "Upload failed";
            }           


            //files
            $postFields['file'] = new CURLFile($uploadfile);

            //metaData USING COUNTER AND UPLOAD NAME DYNAMIC
            $postFields['fileName'] = $_FILES[$upload_name]['name'];
            $postFields['type'] = $_FILES[$upload_name]['type'];
            $postFields['name'] = 'Supporting Docs';
            $postFields['description'] = $_FILES[$upload_name]['name'];

            // initialise the curl request
            $request = curl_init("https://APIURL_HERE");

            // send a file
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $password);
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_PORT, 8443);
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);

            // output the response
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            $send_request = curl_exec($request);

            // close the session
            curl_close($request);
            echo $send_request;

        } 

    }

    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
    print_r($_FILES);
    print_r(getcwd());
    echo '<br>';
    print_r($uploadfile);
    print "</pre>";

}
```

I'm out of ideas, if anyone has experience in this please do help!

Thanks.

Comment: "/home/USER/public_html/top/tmp/client17.jpg due to a File system / Amazon S3 issue /usr/share/tomcat7/.fineract/top/documents/clients/1/8q9sr/home/USER/public_html/top/tmp/"
Does that folder exist and do you have permissions to access it?
And why does the error contain "Amazon S3"? Is it an S3 Mount ?

Comment: No access to it whatsoever, it's on the API's side. Funny thing is that windows doesn't give this error at all